# Progress bar with Bar Chart in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I have a 2 tasks that I would like to keep track of my progress in Google Sheets with a percentage bar chart.

Google Charts is not allowing me to separate the data into two series. They have the same color. I'd like to color them differently. How can I accomplish that? Further, I'd like for 100% to show up for the last tick mark. I added `1` for the max value, but that only increased the scale and did not place a tick mark.

How do I color the series differently (both data points are called 'Bar 1')?

How do I add '100%' as a tick mark?

The data range is `S1:U2`. There is nothing in the S column.

Here's a snapshot of my chart and the data in google sheets.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. The question needs more focus (it has two questions). Please narrow the scope of your question (remove one question, considere to post it as an new question) and add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].